# template Metaprogramming: multiplying a bunch of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, variadic

I need to compute the product of a bunch of numbers at compile time passed to a templated struct. I succeeded to make an *ugly* solution :

```
template<std::size_t n1, std::size_t ...args>
struct mul_all
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = n1 * mul_all<args...>;
};
template<>
struct mul_all<0>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 1;
};
```

The problem is that each time I have to feed 0 to template args to my struct like so

```
int main()
{
    std::cout <<  mul_all<1,2,5,4,5,7,0>::value << " " 
              <<  mul_all<4,2,0>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

**is there any workaround to get read of that last zero?**

note: I am a beginner in TMP.

Comment: Just for kicks, here's a C++14 `constexpr` solution that doesn't use template recursion: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yNbfyOhiN3hLqmpA

Comment: cool!!!is there any way to benchmark it with the other solution?

Comment: Do you mean in terms of compile time? The non-recursive solutions should be about the same, and better than the classic ones involving template recursion, as the recursive ones produce several template instantiations, which cost something (in practice, it starts to matter for relatively large number of template arguments - many tens of them). However, the C++14 dummy array solution is just a workaround for the lack of fold expressions; I would choose C++17 fold expressions whenever available.

Comment: @bogdan - very nice solution, IMHO; you should propose it as asnwer

Comment: @max66 Thanks. It's not really answering the question as asked, that's why I think it belongs in a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, with folding expression, you may directly do

```
template<std::size_t ...args>
struct mul_all
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = (args * ...);
};
```

Before, you have to do the partial specialization:

```
template<std::size_t n1, std::size_t ...args>
struct mul_all
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = n1 * mul_all<args...>::value;
};

template<std::size_t n>
struct mul_all<n>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = n;
};
```

Comment: your proposition is cool but it didn't compile unfortunately, I copyed and past the code, tested with GCC 7.0.0 snapshot but it didn't pass. did you delete `::value` intentionally from here `static constexpr std::size_t value = n1 * mul_all<args...>;`

Comment: @chedynajjar: Indeed `::value` was missing in second snippet, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace your specialization with:

```
template<std::size_t n1, std::size_t ...args>
struct mul_all
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = n1 * mul_all<args...>::value;
};

template<std::size_t n>
struct mul_all<n>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = n;
};
```

Comment: you don't have any recursion in your solution and I don't even see varidic args .

Comment: @chedynajjar: it is a replacement of your full specialization with a partial specializatio: everything else remains as in your approach.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I got a compile-time error : `error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 1)
     static constexpr std::size_t value = n1 * mul_all<args...>::value;`

Comment: The relevant  quote from the standard is 14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 7, last sentence: "When writing a specialization be caraful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to cause self immolation".

Answer (score 3):

One way is to specialize for empty varargs. For that you need the main template to be variadic args only:

```
// main template never used
template<std::size_t ...args> struct mul_all
{
};

// specialization for at least one arg
template<std::size_t n1, std::size_t ...args>
struct mul_all<n1, args...>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = n1 * mul_all<args...>::value;
};

// specialization for empty args
template<>
struct mul_all<>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 1;
};
```

So now you can do:

```
mul_all<1, 2, 3>::value;
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do as far as template recursion goes. There's no need to have to pass in the number of template arguments as a template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The C++17 approach make that nice and simple:

```
template <std::size_t... A>
constexpr std::size_t mul = (A * ... * std::size_t(1u));

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t val = mul<1, 2, 3, 4>;
}
```

For existing C++ versions you'll need to partially specialize the case `mul<v>`:

```
template <std::size_t... V>  struct mul;
template <std::size_t V> struct mul {
    statuc constexpr std::size_t value = V;
};
template <std::size_t V, std::size_t... T> struct mul {
    statuc constexpr std::size_t value = V * mul<T...>::value;
};
template <std::size_t... V>
using mul_v = mul<V...>::value;

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t v = mul_v<1, 2, 3, 4>;
}
```

Comment: I suppose the C++17 version is meant to be more like `(A * ... * 1U)`.

Comment: @bogdan: yes, indeed - currently I can't easily compile but I hope it is corrected now. Thanks!

Comment: You need parens around the fold expression, they're mandatory in the grammar.

Comment: @bogdan: added, too. That is slightly annoying. On the other hand, hopefully fold expressions will be rather rare...

Comment: @bogdan, much cleaner syntax from C++17, and it worked perfectly.